# Netbook won't start after startup with USB attached

Tags: boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, file-recovery, toshiba-laptop

I started my Toshiba Netbook up with a USB flash drive attached, and it messed up the startup process. As soon as I realized my mistake, I stopped the process (I think I just turned it off), took out the USB, and then tried to restart my computer.  Nothing.  Black.

Does anyone know what happened here? And how to fix it?  It is a Toshiba Netbook and it is old, BUT I just so happened to download all my videos of my child as a baby onto it (it was intended to be a backup for my video card memory, but that went bad, so now it's my only copy). How can I get the files off?

Answer (score 0):

> I stopped the process

What was it doing? And what was on the USB flash disk?

Possible solution: Check if bootup options are set properly in the BIOS.

If you just want to get the files off, then you can try running a live CD/USB of a linux distribution and backing up your files or you could detach the hard disk and put it into an external enclosure to access it as an external hard disk.